# mapInnerRoute is not working

Tags: scala, akka, spray, akka-http

I'm trying to create route that would wrap caught exception into my exception that carries user object of logged-in user. Ideally I prefer to put that information into `ContextRequest` in order to use it in my `ExceptionHandler` but it's immutable.

I concluded that the right way to do it is to use `mapInnerRoute` as described in [this example](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/basic-directives/mapInnerRoute.html#Example).

```
def completeWithUserAwareException(user: User) =
  mapInnerRoute { route =>
    ctx =>
      try {
        route(ctx)
      } catch {
        case ex: Throwable =>
          ctx.fail(new ExceptionWithUser(user, 0, ex))
      }
  }
```

which I use like this

```
val authenticatedRoutes = myAuthorization { user =>
    completeWithUserAwareException(user) {
    pathPrefix("admin") {
      (get & path("plugins")) {
          complete {
            ""
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Content of `completeWithUserAwareException` is never invoked. I suspect it has something to do with dynamic nature of outer route.

How can I achieve my goal of passing user context information to exception handler ?

Comment: Where do you throw an exception? Also, there's the `handleExceptions` directive which you should use to make sure never to lose an exception (the route returns a `Future[RouteResult]` which may not fail immediately but only later on, `handleExceptions` makes sure your exception handler is called in all cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
def completeWithUserAwareException(user: User) =
  handleExceptions(
    ExceptionHandler {
      case NonFatal(ex) => failWith(new ExceptionWithUser(user, 0, ex))
    })
```

Comment: I suspect in to-be-released you've switched to partial function. I've changed your code to one that works with 1.0

Comment: Is there snapshot version of akka-http ?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Not sure if there was a version where it worked without the extra wrapper (by implicit conversion) but AFAICS it still is necessary.

Comment: No, there are no snapshot builds but a new version is going to be published quite soon (most likely still in October).